# Android can't get current location of device

Tags: android, location, maps

I am trying to get current location of my android phone and show it on map. It works on another device but my device shows only world map provided my device's GPS is turned on.Here is my code:

```
  if(locationManagerCheck .isLocationServiceAvailable()){
        if (googleMap == null) {
            try {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Harita oluşturulamadı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
                        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
                        // MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Konumunuz");
                        //marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
                        //googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                    }
                });
            }}

    }else{
        locationManagerCheck .createLocationServiceError(Anasayfa.this);
    }
```

Please Guide.

Comment: what is your phone OS version? 6.0 or above?

Comment: my phone is 6.0 I tried on 4.4, it can find location but on my phone only shows map

Comment: for Android 6 you have to request permissions in runtime.

Comment: THANK YOU it works with runtime permissions :)

Answer (score 0):

check all the below conditions:

1) You need to create android map api key on google developers console.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

2) if you have already created the api key then check that you have pasted the same key in your key file.

if you have created via android studio then "res/values/google_maps_api.xml" is the file where you need to paste the key.

3) if above two conditions are true then check on console that you have pasted the right Sh1 fingerprint and package name while generating the key. You will find your Sh1 and package name in google_maps_api.xml file.

4) if all above conditions are checked then check if you have the uses permission in manifest file or not..?

5) if everything above is fine then paste your logcat or error.
then only SO can help you more.

youe need to give "internet" permission and access "fine or coarse location" or both depending on your uses.

if you want some reference about how to get user current location then please have a look on below link: 
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

or search on SO you will find many ans.

Comment: Ok,  but it works other phones.  On my phone,  map works but can't find location.  I tried find location other apps on my phone,  gps is working. Problem is only on my app

Comment: post your logcat or error so we can figure it out what the problem is..??

Comment: or do following steps:

Comment: sorry i accidentally press enter do below steps : 
1)First open Google map application in the respective phone your getting error once Google map application show your current location then try in your application. Now your application may find the device current location.
Sometimes we forgot to check the currentLocation null condition and if your using method like "getlastKnownLocation" or something like that then this is the  problem.

Comment: it doesnt work :( but i realized that, on google map app gps icon appears on  screen but on my app it never works. i think my app cant start my gps :D

Comment: in that case post your error log then only i can help you further.